# How to exclude h:selectBooleanCheckbox from p:tab title?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The problem is as follows: I need to put checkbox in Primefaces p:tab title via facet, but when I click the checkbox I don't want tab to open.

Here is a code snippet.

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" activeIndex="">               
    <p:tab rendered="#{condition}">
        <f:facet name="title">
            <div>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="simple-checkbox" value="#{someValue}" >
                    <p:ajax event="click" process="@this"
                            action="#{some action}"
                            update="some elements" global="false" />
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <h:outputText value="some text" />
            </div>
        </f:facet>
        Tab Body
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `event.stopPropagation();` to the `onclick` of your `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox`

Like this

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="event.stopPropagation();"...
```

Also you better don't nest `p:ajax` with inside JSF native components and vice versa...

`f:ajax` is meant to use with native JSF components

`p:ajax` is meant to use with PrimeFaces components

It is fine to have both , Primefaces components and JSF native components in one page, just make sure to use `p:ajax` in Primefaces components and `f:ajax` in JSF native components

Comment: That worked a charm! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! PS. Could You elaborate on that : "Aldo you better don't mix p:ajax with plain JSF components and vice versa..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Since event are passed to their parents. There is a way to prevent that using jQuery by adding this to your view :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $(".ui-accordion-header .simple-checkbox").click(function(e)
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Note : I've added `.ui-accordion-header` to selector to prevent applying this to all your checkboxes.

**More info :**

- [jQuery stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I think Daniel's suggestion is more practical. Thanks anyways Alexandre!.

Comment: @Kuba at least I've put on the right track since I've answered before :)